# SQL: Group SUM values by date ranges and show in multiple columns by date

Tags: sql

I have a SQL table showing charge amounts per person and an associated date.  I'm looking to create a printout of each person's charges per month.  I have the following code which will show me everyone's data for ONE month but I'd like to put this in one report without having to rerun this for every month's date range.  Is there a way to pull this data all at once? Essentially I'd like the columns to show:

Last Name  January  February  March Etc

name         amt        amt     amt

Here is my code to pull this data for April as an example.  You'll see the dates are codes as YYYYMMDD.  This code works perfectly for one month at a time.

```
select pm.last_name, SUM(amt) as Total_Charge from charges c
inner join provider_mstr pm ON c.rendering_id = pm.provider_id
where begin_date_of_service >= '20150401' and begin_date_of_service <= '20150431'
group by pm.last_name
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A generic solution uses SUM over CASEs:

```
select pm.last_name, 
  SUM(case when begin_date_of_service >= '20150101' and begin_date_of_service  < '20150201' then amt else 0 end) as Total_Charge_Jan,
  SUM(case when begin_date_of_service >= '20150201' and begin_date_of_service  < '20150301' then amt else 0 end) as Total_Charge_Feb,
  SUM(case when begin_date_of_service >= '20150301' and begin_date_of_service  < '20150401' then amt else 0 end) as Total_Charge_Mar,
...
from charges c
inner join provider_mstr pm ON c.rendering_id = pm.provider_id
where begin_date_of_service >= '20150101' and begin_date_of_service  < '20160101'
group by pm.last_name
```

Depending on your DBMS you might have a PIVOT function or similar...

Answer (score 3):

Change SUM(amt) as Total_Charge to the following for each period

```
SUM(CASE WHEN begin_date_of_service BETWEEN '20150401' AND '20150430' THEN amt ELSE 0 END) AS April_Amt

SUM(CASE WHEN begin_date_of_service BETWEEN '20150301' AND '20150331' THEN amt ELSE 0 END) AS March_Amt
```

And update WHERE clause to include all date ranges for pull.

Comment: This is not a valid CASE statement, `THEN` and `ELSE` is missing.

Comment: Close, now remove the superfluous commas :-)

Answer (score 1):

A condition will evaluate to 1 or 0 in a product, so you could use the following approach to do a selective sum:

```
select 
   pm.last_name, 
   SUM(amt * (begin_date_of_service >= '20150401' and begin_date_of_service <= '20150431')) AS 'april', 
   SUM(amt * (begin_date_of_service >= '20150501' and begin_date_of_service <= '20150530')) AS 'may'
   ...
from charges c
inner join provider_mstr pm ON c.rendering_id = pm.provider_id
group by pm.last_name
```